# I cant figure out the right solution yet i feel so close. Anyone can help me out/

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

**Metric Dictionary
Write a function that calculates the mean, median, variance, standard deviation, minimum and maximum of of list of items. You can assume the given list is contains only numerical entries, and you may use numpy functions to do this.**

```
def dictionary_of_metrics(items):
    gauteng = {
       'mean': round(np.mean(items),2),
       'median': round(np.median(items),2),
       'std': round(np.std(items), 2),
       'var': round(np.var(items),2),
       'min': round(np.min(items),2),
       'max': round(np.max(items),2)  }

   return gauteng
```

****This is the error message I get****

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10816/1906678183.py in 
----> 1 dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng)

NameError: name 'gauteng' is not defined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. Your question title should not talk about how you feel, and it should not simply [ask for help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Instead, it should use a question word like "why" or "what", and thus ask us *what you need to know in order to solve the problem*. It is your responsibility [to figure that out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) after first [understanding what went wrong](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and ask the question in your own terms - don't just paste a homework assignment, code and error message; tell us - in your own words - *what the code is supposed to do*. Show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` and formatting as code. Then ask your question, making it clear *why you are confused* (if you are) and/or *what help you need*.

Comment: Finally, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure that other people can see the problem exactly as you have it. Notice how the error message you show, references a different piece of the code (the part where you *call* this function)? You should show that part, too. After all, the error is explicitly telling you that the problem is *there*. You can also start the debugging process by *understanding* how the code is supposed to work. When you write `dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng)` to call the function, what do you expect the `(gauteng)`  part to mean? Why?

Comment: So close yet so far... Welcome to my life.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the **list of items** list called *'gauteng'* before calling the function? If not, you have to create the **list of items** before using it as a function argument. The code would be

```
def dictionary_of_metrics(items):
    gauteng = {
       'mean': round(np.mean(items),2),
       'median': round(np.median(items),2),
       'std': round(np.std(items), 2),
       'var': round(np.var(items),2),
       'min': round(np.min(items),2),
       'max': round(np.max(items),2)  }

    return gauteng

gauteng = [1,2,3,4,5]

dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng)
```

The function creates the `gauteng` dictionary in it's local scope. This cannot be accessed globally and it cannot be used for as function argument.